# How to recover from a black screen after BIOS update?

Tags: laptop, bios, lenovo-laptop

I am using a Lenovo Ideapad 5 15ALC05 and a few days ago I had a notification from Lenovo Vantage that there was a BIOS and some drivers updates, ready to be installed. Normally, I am always sceptic about bios updates, but this time I just installed it.

After the installation in windows the computer rebooted. A black screen with letters followed and the laptop was beeping. It seemd like it was just updating the bios. After the update the computer rebooted, but then never started. The power led is on, as well as the leds of the capslock, esc and numlock button, but the screen is just black.

When I start the laptop with <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> pressed, the <kbd>caps lock</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd> and num lock LEDs are not on. Not sure if something is going on there. I already tried buttons like <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> etc. and also the Lenovo recovery button at the side of my laptop, but nothing happened.

I also already tried to connect an external display with hdmi to my laptop, but that did not seem to work either.

I am wondering if I really need to send my laptop to Lenovo for a repair, or that I can try some things. Maybe a BIOS recovery, or something?

Comment: Try starting with a Bootable USB Key (Windows ISO made bootable will work). If that starts, it may not be a BIOS issue. Windows Updates typically do not update BIOS - that is a separate procedure.

Comment: @John The only thing is that I can not choose the device I want to boot with, because I can't enter any boot menu or bios at all. Will still try your suggestion. Always worth the shot.

Comment: Try a specific recovery USB for your Lenovo machine as that does not require a change to BIOS setttigs.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get into the BIOS using the right buttons
(usually F2, F12, Esc), then the BIOS is bricked.

Without a working BIOS, it's impossible to update the BIOS.
You need special equipment available in repair-shops for forcing
the update.

Answer : Yes, you need to get the computer repaired by a professional.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. So there is no way to repair a bricked BIOS/Motherboard? I have seen some articles saying that you can make some kind of recovery USB. Other people said to me that when I send it to lenovo, they will replace the entire motherboard (will take 2 months due to not having it on stock). What do you suggest? Just send it to them or try a recovery?

Comment: Strange advice: How would you use the USB without a BIOS? I understand that this computer is not new. I don't think that there is anything mechanically wrong with the motherboard, so no point in replacing it. Ask Lenovo Support, but also any repairshop near you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The laptop has been bought two months ago, directly at the Lenovo website. Still have two-year warranty. When I have a USB plugged in and press FN+R when I start the computer, I can see the USB blinking for a few seconds, meaning that it is being read. So maybe there is hope?

Comment: If the laptop is new, get in touch with Support. This happened because of their software, so not by error on your part.